# How to play GIF while it's loading - React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

How can I play a GIF while it's still loading in React Native?
I do not want to wait until it's loaded.

Comment: It may not be possible with the on-board tools. This sounds like a case where it's worth looking at native iOS solutions and trying to bridge them into your RN app

Comment: Not sure whether this does what you need, but this (for Swift) may be worth a look https://github.com/kaishin/Gifu

Comment: What does 'loading' exactly mean?

Comment: when you open a gif in browser it's starting to play just like a video. but in react native it's waiting until the gif completely loaded(downloaded from remote). @martinarroyo